# Is "prefixed by" correct?

Tags: phrase-usage

When I write the following sentence, the grammar/spelling checker running on my Mac always suggests me to use *prefixed to* or *prefaced with*.

> Functions implemented by a module should always have their names **prefixed by** the module name.

What I mean is that, if the module name is user, the function name should not be `load()`, but `user_load()`.

Is it correct to use *prefixed by*, or should I use another phrase?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both *prefixed to* and *prefixed by* are correct, but they have different meanings.

If A is *prefixed to* B, A is the prefix and B is what the prefix is added to. In this case the end result is A_B.  To use your example, you could say that `user` is *prefixed to* `load()` to create `user_load()`.

If A is *prefixed by* B, B is the prefix and A is what the prefix is added to. The result is B_A. For your example, you would say that `load()` is *prefixed by* `user` to create `user_load()`.

To state this in more general terms for your entire project, you might make either of these statements:

> Each method name related to the `user` object is *prefixed by* the string `user`.
>
> The string `user` is *prefixed to* each method name related to the `user` object.

And concerning the sentence in your question:

> Functions implemented by a module should always have their names *prefixed by* the module name.

It is indeed correct, because the suffix (function name) is *prefixed by* the prefix (module name).

Comment: What about 'prefixed with'?

Comment: @NS.X. "prefixed with" is not ungrammatical, but it is uncommon and, in the kiam case, would not be used.

Comment: @Carlo I agree that it's not the best choice in this case (as Wendi says, *"by"* is better), but I disagree that *"prefixed with"* is uncommon.  I think it's actually *more* common.