# Using the phrase "prefixed by"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, sentence-structure, prefixes

Which one seems correct?

```
non-xx domains (those that are not prefixed with "xx" sub-domains)
```

Or

```
non-xx domains (those that are not prefixed by "xx" sub-domains)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give this a quick answer, as it is not, as far as I can see, an exact duplicate of [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6653/is-prefixed-by-correct), albeit it is related.

'Prefixed by' and 'prefixed with' are used just about equally today, [according to Google NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prefixed%20by%2C%20prefixed%20with&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprefixed%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprefixed%20with%3B%2Cc0). Either is fine, although in the past 'prefixed by' was used far more.

Comment: Yeah, you're quite right. After casting my dup closevote, I realised that the only "answer" to the issue about whether *prefixed **with*** is okay, on that earlier page, is buried away in a comment: [*I disagree that "prefixed with" is uncommon. I think it's actually more common.*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6653/is-prefixed-by-correct#comment10333_6656) The truth of which (for AmE, but not *quite* yet for BrE) is borne out by the NGram I specified for myself (before discovering that I could have just waited for your link to appear here! :)